# How to link to users/id/microposts in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need create a link to `users/id/microposts` where `id` is the user id. I was wondering how I could do that with `link_to`?

The HTML code is I am using for the moment is :

```
<strong><a href="/users/<%= @user.id %>/microposts">Microposts</a></strong> <%= user.microposts.count %>
```

Which renders the following :

```
<a href="/users/1/microposts">Microposts</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In routes.rb, you should have something like this:

```
match '/users/:id/microposts' => 'microposts#index_by_user', :as => :microposts_by_user
```

and in view, you can do like this:

```
<%= link_to "Microposts", microposts_by_user_path( @user) %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. I used the `index` action instead of `index_by_user` though. Is this less idiomatic?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have your routes setup correctly, that would be a nested route for the microposts, In rails 3 it would be

```
resources :users do
  resources :microposts
end
```

Then in your view, with link_to you can

```
<%= link_to "Microposts", user_microposts_path(user) %>
```

This might be current_user, @user ... whatever user object you want the microposts, it might be from

```
@users.each do |user|
  <%= link_to "Microposts", user_microposts_path(user) %>
end
```

OR

```
<%= link_to "Microposts", user_microposts_path(current_user) %>
```

EDIT: Added in the user object I forgot to passin and some examples with it.

Comment: I think you need to pass a `User` object into `user_microposts_path` in this case.

Comment: I tried your solution, but I got this error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in MicropostsController#index  - Couldn't find User without an ID`. I guess I need to use @nitecoder's solution? Can you tell me how?